# Rebind action assigned to ajax link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is a link to delete a post:

```
<a id="post_232_destroy" class="postDestroy" rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/someurl">Delete</a>
```

javascript (compiled from coffescript):

```
function() {

  jQuery(function() {
    return $("a.postDestroy").bind("ajax:success", function(event, data) {
      $('#post_' + data.post_id).remove();
    }).bind("ajax:error", function() {
      alert('Please try again');
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

I'm adding new post via ajax, so bind to Delete button is missing, for each recently added post. Post is deleted but ajax:success is not called, so div is not removed.
How can I bind it again ?

Answer (score 0):

On each adding of new post you can unbind all posts and then bind again.

```
$("a.postDestroy").unbind("ajax:success");
$("a.postDestroy").unbind("ajax:error");
$("a.postDestroy").bind("ajax:success", function(event, data) {
  $('#post_' + data.post_id).remove();
}).bind("ajax:error", function() {
  alert('Please try again');
});
});
```

EDIT:
Try using jquery "live" function instead of "bind":

```
$("a.postDestroy").live("ajax:success", function(event, data) {
  $('#post_' + data.post_id).remove();
}).live("ajax:error", function() {
  alert('Please try again');
});
});
```

Comment: It is some solution, but its not very DRY. Actions for success and error are a bit more complex, I just pruned them to make code more readable.

Comment: I suggest using jquery "live" function instead of "bind" function. The example is in my post, which was edited.